# Asp.Net and Sql Server Express

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express

I'm new to Asp.Net.

I want to install SQL Server Express on a different Windows PC than the one the site will be hosted on. I am planning on using MVC5 and Web Api.

I have seen that one can use LocalDB but this will not work for me as I want to run queries on the DB from my side. Is this possible ?

As far as I understand IIS should also be running on the server/domain that is hosting the ASP.NET.

Or should I just install everything on a single windows machine and go from there as I'm a single developer.

Lastly, I can maybe connect to my existing MySql db from the asp.net project but I am not sure how difficult this will be.

Sorry if these are a silly questions. I'm still finding my feet in this area and I need to find them fast .

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: +1 for nice writing .. i think the question will be closed but for me it is ok to ask question .. and there should be a stack network site where beginners can ask such question

Comment: Now for your answer i m not familiar with MVC5 but i m quiet sure that you can connect to a remote SQL Serve express .. there will not be any problem with that .. the only thing you need to see that SQL server is configured to accept the remote connection and you can connect to mysql DB too but i will advice you should work with SQL serve when you are programing in ASP .net